# How do I add global types to eslint/emmet in vscode?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint

NOTE: This is **NOT** a typescript question. I'm using JavaScript, not TypeScript

ESLint/Emmet in VSCode is aware of certain global types. For example: I type

```
const ctx = AudioC
```

And vscode/eslint/emmet auto completes it to `AudioContext`.

[image]

And if I continue and type

```
  const ctx = new AudioContext();
  ctx.create
```

it clearly knows the type since it provides completions for that type, not just that it's a global

[image]

How do I add new global completions/type data? For example these types

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@webgpu/types

even if I have to convert them to some other form

As it is VSCode/ESlint/Emmet are not aware of them.

[image]

Note: I'm not asking about `/* global someName */` nor am I asking about ["specifying globals"](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/configuring/language-options#specifying-globals). Neither of those adds new types.

Also note, I'm asking how to add them at a global level. In other words, if just create a new file and type

```
const a = GPUBufferUsage.
```

It needs to complete, the same as if I had typed

```
const b = navigator.
```

[image]

I didn't have to add any special comments or annotations to the file. the types are added at a global level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

half of the solution:

VSCode uses typescript to do its type completion even when in JavaScript

See VSCode docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript

To add global types you can add a `jsconfig.json` file. The `jsconfig.json` file has the same format as a `tsconfig.json` file except it defaults to `allowJs: true`. Otherwise it's the same so you can configure it the same. For the referenced package above something like this seems to work

`jsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@webgpu/types"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/node_modules/*"]
}
```

and adding the types for the package above with

```
npm install --save-dev @webgpu/types
```

[image]

This doesn't help eslint. It still complains. But you can manually add them to your `.eslintrc` file. For this particular file I extracted them with

```
grep "declare var" ./node_modules/@webgpu/types/dist/index.d.ts | sed 's/declare var \(.*\):.*$/"\1",/'
```

If there is an more standard way to get eslint to recognize those globals please add an answer.